# Accessing object key via dynamically changed variable key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I'm not sure how to explain correctly in a title, but here is the situation:

Having three available angles: front, left and right:

```
captures: {
  front: { img: '', correct: false },
  left: { img: '', correct: false },
  right: { img: '', correct: false }
},
```

I have defined a default variable named `this.currentAngle = 'front'`.

I want to access a value from **CAPTURES** object list within **currentAngle**.

This does not work:

```
this.captures.[this.currentAngle].img
```

nor this one, logically

```
this.captures.this.currentAngle.img
```

What's the correct approach ?

Comment: `this.captures[this.currentAngle].img`

Comment: almost:
this.captures[this.currentAngle].img

Comment: @connexo oh you speed typer!!! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, just remove the dot before the opening square bracket from your first attempt:

```js
const captures = {
  front: { img: 'f', correct: false },
  left: { img: 'l', correct: false },
  right: { img: 'r', correct: false }
}

let prop = 'front'

console.log(captures[prop].img)
```